# Firebase Extension - Resize

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, image-resizing, firebase-extensions

I wanted to try the Resize-Firebase-Extension. Configuration seemed very easy and pictures i upload to that bucket are being handled. The new /thumbs folder appeared and telling by the given size a much smaller version of these images is displayed in the console. However these pics cant be opened (firebase console seems to crash: a new tab opens and redirects to project overview). Also the preview is not showing in console when in the thumbs folder.

I did add the content metadata like this:

```
if (byteArray != null){
            StorageMetadata metadata = new StorageMetadata.Builder()
                    .setContentType("image/jpeg")
                    .setCustomMetadata("isGroupImage", isGroup)
                    .setCustomMetadata("areaNumber", userNumber)
                    .build();
            mUploadtask =mStorageRef.putBytes(byteArray, metadata).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    callback.onSuccess(mStorageRef.toString());
```

Anything else to be taken care of for the function to work? Anyone else facing that problem?

Comment: The Firebase console has been known not to preview images that are added via backend code.  Please file a bug report with [Firebase support](https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support) directly for that.  If you have general feedback or suggestions about extension, you can file that on the [project GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/extensions).

Comment: The problem is not only in console, i just checked. The thumbs dont work in app either. Any idea?

Comment: It sounds like you want to use the second link I provided.

Comment: @Nick can you try updating to the latest version of the extension and see if it works?